# How to replace an value in an array with checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to arrange a checkbox array with jQuery. I have managed to get the values to add to the array in order and remove the correct one, but for the life of me i cannot get it to replace the removed value with the newly selected value. Currently it just adds the new value to the end of the array.

Here's my code so far:

```
var array = [];
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                // Add the new element if checked:
                array.push($(this).attr('value'));
                $('#ff_elem512').val(array);
            }
            else {
                // Remove the element if unchecked:
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if (array[i] == $(this).attr('value')) {
                        array.splice(i, 1);
                        $('#ff_elem512').val(array);
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(array);
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your html look like? What is $('#ff_elem512')?

Comment: Have you tried to replace $(this).attr('checked') by $(this).prop('checked')?

Comment: @Winter
$('#ff_elem512') is a input where im sending the array

Comment: @SylvainB
no i haven't ill try now - 

Tried the code works as it did doesnt replace values though

Answer (score 0):

You can always set your array when you click some checkbox, like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
  array = [];
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( function () {
    array.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(array);
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ssyxvv2/

**UPDATE**: If you want to preserver the clicked order, use this instead:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var elem=$(this);
      if (this.checked) {
        array.push($(this).val())
    } else {
        array = array.filter(function(x){
            return x != $(elem).val() });
    }
    console.log(array);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but the selected checkboxes must be set in order of selection.

Comment: i need it like when i remove any value then add new value in the same place as removed value with preserving the order. not remove value add new value to the end of array. thanks

Comment: Well, I think now you know how to remove the item, you can try to change the code, or use any of other examples and you will do it, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery is  function instead of attr like Below

```
var array = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is('checked')) {
            // Add the new element if checked:
            array.push($(this).attr('value'));
            $('#ff_elem512').val(array);
        }
        else {
            // Remove the element if unchecked:
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] == $(this).attr('value')) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                    $('#ff_elem512').val(array);
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(array);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        // Add the new element if checked:
        if (array.indexOf($(this).val()) < 0) {
            array.push($(this).val());
          } 
        } else {
          // Remove the element if unchecked:
          if (array.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
              array.splice(array.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
            }
        }
        $('#ff_elem512').val(array.join(", "));
        console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />One
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />Two
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />Three
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />Four
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />Five
<br />
<input type="text" id="ff_elem512" />
```

Comment: I need it to remove a value then add a new value in the same place as the old value was